# Holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disk s.t. |Re$f(z)|<1$, sup$_{z\in\mathcal{D}}$Im$f(z)=100$, inf$_{z\in\mathcal{D}}$Im$f(z)=-100$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disk $\mathcal{D}=\{z:|z|<1\}$ such that |Re$f(z)|<1$ for all $z$, sup$_{z\in\mathcal{D}}$Im$f(z)=100$, inf$_{z\in\mathcal{D}}$Im$f(z)=-100$?

Clearly we are looking for a mapping from the unit disc into a bounded space, whose real values are in $(0,1)$ and imaginary values in $[-100,100]$. The Schwartz lemma conditions are not fulfilled. Would you have any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Riemann's Mapping Theorem, since $A=\{x+iy:0<x<1,-100<y<100\}$
is simply connected and $\ne\Bbb C$, there is a conformal equivalence
$f:D\to\Bbb C$.

Comment: thanks I understood it. Just one remark: We are given that |Re$f(z)|<1$. So doesn't it mean that $A=\{x+iy:-1<x<1,-100<y<100\}$?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer You did say "whose real values are in $(0,1)$ and imaginary values in $[−100,100]$".

Comment: Correct, but looking more carefully at the problem, we have that the modulus of the real part is between 0 and 1

Comment: Shouldn't this be "there is a conformal equivalence $f: D \to "A"$?